# How to send files from folder recursively to command in linux console?

Tags: linux, console, docco

I want to generate docs for coffee-script files. I want to use Docco.

When i use:

```
docco client/coffee/*
```

it throws error. I think because folders are in file list.
When i use:

```
docco client/coffee/*.coffee
```

it cant' find some files, because i havent anithing in root folder.

How to give all *.coffee files recursievly to command in console?

Comment: @jgb: `**/*.coffee` does not seem to work for subfolders on multiple levels. If I have multiple levels, I still need to use `**/*.coffee`, `**/**/*.coffee`, `**/**/**/*.coffee`, etc. Anyway to solve this easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do it

```
$ find client/coffee/ -name '*.coffee' -exec docco {} +

$ find client/coffee/ -name '*.coffee' | xargs docco
```

However, note that the latter way does not work if there is space in file name, unless you use `find -print0` with combination of `xargs -0`.

Additionally, if you are using bash, you can use `**/*.coffee` with setting `shopt -s globstar`